# How to generate variable based on conditions across multiple variables with by:?

Tags: conditional-statements, stata, generate

I'm trying to `generate` a new variable using a `by:` prefix based on conditions  across multiple observations. So for a given group (let's say ID #1) there could be 10 observations, and I want to make a new variable based on two conditions (e.g., does weight exceed > 160 lbs and does height exceed 65 inches, if so new variable=1 for a given ID; so even if one observation of ID #1 includes values 150 lbs and 60 inches but another observation includes value 165 lbs and 66 inches, the new  variable should be 1)

```
sysuse autotype
sort rep78
generate Domestic=1 if foreign==0
replace Domestic=0 if foreign==1
generate Foreign=1 if foreign==1
replace Foreign=0 if foreign==0

by rep78: generate both_types=1 if Domestic==1 & Foreign==1
*gives me all missing*

*try again after dropping*
generate both_types=0
by rep78: replace both_types=1 if (Domestic==1 & Foreign==1)
\*\*no changes made
```

What I am trying to do above is make a new variable `both_types` that is =1 IF within `rep78` there are both domestic and foreign cars. So for the 11 cars that are `rep78`=5 2 are domestic, and the rest are foreign, the variable should be 1, while for the 2 cars that are `rep78`=1, they are both domestic, so `both_types` should be =0 for all observations where `rep78`=1.

Comment: I've translated your question into Stata language. We are not in spreadsheet state any more! Column means variable, row means observation, and `by:` is a prefix command, not an operator.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your code leads to comparisons between observations in the same group. A `by:` prefix does not itself imply any calculation different within groups unless the rest of the code does that. One way to see this is to consider that

```
bysort group : gen answer = 42
```

does nothing different from

```
gen answer = 42
```

any more than "in your own kitchen: add 2 + 2" does anything different from "in your friend's kitchen: add 2 + 2" or in general that `by kitchen: gen four = 2 + 2` differs from `gen four = 2 + 2`.

What follows the `by:` prefix must entail some combination of evidence from the observations within each group to make a difference.

What you want for your second example is just

```
sysuse auto, clear 
bysort rep78 (foreign) : gen both_types = foreign[1] != foreign[_N]
```

which for an indicator variable such as `foreign` which has values 0 and 1 (and is never missing) gives the same result as

```
bysort rep78 (foreign) : gen both_types2 = foreign[1] == 0 & foreign[_N] == 1
```

The logic in both cases is that if you sort on `foreign` within `rep78` then if there is any 0 value the first value in each group will be 0 and similarly if there is any 1 value then the last value in each group will be 1.

So we took account of any variations within a group by sorting beforehand and then comparing first and last values.

See the FAQ https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/listing-observations-in-group/

However, missing values will frustrate that small technique.

So, often and for your first example too, we need more general technique. I will refer you to another FAQ for more technique https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/create-variable-recording/ but here will solve your second problem in a different way that will extend to your first problem.

We can count occurrences of 1 and 0 by

```
bysort rep78 : egen count1 = total(foreign == 1) 
bysort rep78 : egen count0 = total(foreign == 0)
```

and that lets us go straight to an answer which is

```
gen both = count1 & count0
```

which will be 1 if both arguments are positive (because positive values are treated as true) and 0 otherwise (because  0 `&` positive (or the reverse) results in false; note that 0 & 0 also counts as false, although that wouldn't arise for this example). Counts will never be negative. You might need to learn, or refresh your memory on, Stata's rules for true and false, say through https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/

Missing values are ignored by either calculation, as you would usually wish.

The first problem then yields to something like

```
bysort ID: egen count_tall = total(height > 65 & height < .) 
by ID: egen count_heavy = total(weight > 160 & weight < .)
```

after which a solution similar to the previous is set for you as an exercise. But note how you need to exclude missing values, which are treated as arbitrarily large when using `>`. Naturally if you don't have any missing values, you can ignore the code to trap them, but it does no harm.

In fact you could go there more directly with

```
bysort ID: egen count_tall_heavy = total(height > 165 & height < . & weight > 160 & weight < .)
```

which gives you a count, after which a 0,1 indicator is given by

```
gen any_tall_heavy = count_tall_heavy > 0
```